# How to pass an object from the main to another module

Tags: python, spacy

The following code runs without error

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

test = nlp(' FWCA rate of pay')

phrase_pattern = [r'Rate of Pay']
pattern_name = 'RATES'
patterns = [nlp.make_doc(name) for name in phrase_pattern]

matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr='LOWER')
matcher.add(pattern_name, None, *patterns)

matches = matcher(test)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    matched_span = test[start:end]
    print(matched_span.text)     
    print('- ', matched_span.sent.text)

# Returned:
rate of pay
-   FWCA rate of pay
```

I then moved part of the code into a separate module so that I could use it in another project

```
# my_module.py

def find_matches(pattern_name, phrase_pattern, doc, attr="LOWER"):
    import spacy
    from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

    patterns = [nlp.make_doc(name) for name in phrase_pattern]
    matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr='LOWER')
    matcher.add(pattern_name, None, *patterns)

    matches = matcher(doc)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        matched_span = doc[start:end]
        print(matched_span.text)     
        print('- ', matched_span.sent.text)
```

But when I ran this code, I got an error

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
from my_module import find_matches

nlp1 = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
test = nlp1(' FWCA rate of pay')

find_matches(pattern_name, phrase_pattern, test, attr="LOWER")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-1bc18aa51d61> in <module>()
     10 matcher.add(pattern_name, None, *patterns)
     11 
---> 12 matches = matcher(test)
     13 for match_id, start, end in matches:
     14     matched_span = test[start:end]

phrasematcher.pyx in spacy.matcher.phrasematcher.PhraseMatcher.__call__()

phrasematcher.pyx in spacy.matcher.phrasematcher.PhraseMatcher.get_lex_value()

strings.pyx in spacy.strings.StringStore.__getitem__()

KeyError: "[E018] Can't retrieve string for hash '12488114723688465754'."
```

The reason for the error was that the `nlp` object inside the function `find_matches` was different to the `nlp1` object in the main.

My questions are:

1. How can I pass the `nlp1` object into the function `find_matches`, that is, I won't declare `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')` inside the function? Is that possible?
2. If the function can't inhere the `nlp1` object, how can I overcome the problem?

My thinking is that I should pass the raw text as an argument of the function, then create a `doc` object inside it like this

```
find_matches(pattern_name, phrase_pattern, text, attr="LOWER"):
    doc = nlp(text)
    ....
    ....
```

Is that efficient?

Comment: Why do you `spacy.load(...` twice?

Comment: Because one is for the `my_module` and one is for the `main` (in this case, the Jupyter Notebook) otherwise it results in error `nlp is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Answering your questions:

> 1) How can I pass the nlp1 object into the function find_matches, that is, I won't declare nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg') inside the function? Is that possible?

You can pass nlp as an attribute, since it is an object. When you do spacy.load(), you're building a pipeline object with the embeddings, configs and machine learning models that you passed as argument (such as "en_core_web_lg").

> 2) If the function can't inhere the nlp1 object, how can I overcome the problem?

You can pass the object as argument, as answered above. However, why would this be a problem? In fact if you're doing some product for deployment, I would recommend that you made nlp a **class variable** instantiated at initialization.

*Unless you're working with different pipelines*, **there's no reason to load spacy more than once**, especially taking into account that this is a slow process (it reads from disk).

And, finally:

```
find_matches(pattern_name, phrase_pattern, text, attr="LOWER"):
    doc = nlp(text)
    ....
    ....
```

> Is that efficient?

Yes, that's a very efficient method. When you make doc = nlp(text), you're using this nlp global object to produce the results from your pipeline processing, which is individual to each text, since it carries the text tags, spans, etc.

-- Complement after the author's own solution --

Another efficient solution is to pass the "doc" object as a reference, especially if it is going to be used by several different functions in a functional programming style. This doc object contains all pertinent results from the processed text.

Comment: Thanks, Tiago. I posted the question before bed last night and by the morning I had the same idea as per your suggestion, that is, passing the `nlp` as argument in the `find_matches()`. Consequently, I think it would be more efficient to pass object `doc` instead of `text` in the function too because global object `doc` is used in other previous steps of the pipeline.